# what this methods does isExternalStorageRemovable and isExternalStorageEmulated

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Sorry if this question have been asked before . But i didnt understand . Can any one give me good explanation of it with an example . what is difference between both of them  isExternalStorageRemovable and isExternalStorageEmulated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In old android devices external storage was directed to SD card that you could physically remove. In new android devices external storage is directed to a directory on the data partition (with FUSE on top of it) - an emulated SD card.

So, isExternalStorageEmulated will tell you if your storage is on data partition and isExternalStorageRemovable will tell you if your storage is SD card. Most of the time they will return opposite output but I guess you can find a rare device that its external storage is a separated partition so both of them will return false.